# How do you turn off the repetitive coach in Madden?

Tags: madden-12

How do you completely shut off the in game commentary? I'm sick of intercepting the ball and hearing "You're in the shotgun here so use the extra time". I turned off the sound, but I like the crowd/field noise.

Comment: Don't recall the settings and don't have '12, but pretty sure there is a setting under Game options > Volume > Commentary or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

You can turn off the coordinator through "Game Options" --> "Coordinator Audio" and turn off the announcer through "Volume Control" --> "In-Game Commentary"